# How to configure Jenkins to run Python scripts?

Tags: python, jenkins, configuration, automated-tests

I started learning Jenkins using Python 3. Trying to run file.py in Jenkins with Docker.
Jenkins cannot find the exact directory despite the fact that I have specified the exact path to the file in the variable.

The method with variables did not help. I also failed using the Python plugin.
The only solution I see on the net is to create variables and select the Windows command in the build:

`SET PATH = %your_path_name% python your_file_location\filename.py`

It didn't help either.
Here is part of what the console outputs:

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.\<init\>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)

Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/wqw"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I know that you can pull the script from GitHub, but I want to understand why the problem appeared and how to solve it?

UPDATE: I chose the shell command 'PATH=$Path1' and the build was successful. However, this only points to the correct directory and does not check the code itself in the file?

```
Started by user USER
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dede
[dede] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4966087103275671986.sh
+ PATH=C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pytest\test_demo.py 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can you add the command you're trying to run? If this is a pipeline job, can you add your pipeline code?

Comment: SET PATH = %Path% 
python location\filename.py

I use this via windows command
python ./file.py  for shell command also didn't work

Comment: Error "/var/..." suggests OS is Unix, not Windows.

Comment: @IanW Thanks! Does this mean I need to use a different command ? But the shell didn't work either

Comment: MacOS is Unix-ish, so should use execute shell step: it's a bundled plugin. Then use full path to executable, ie :`/path/to/python /path/to/filename.py`. Typically, `/path/to filename.py` would be relative to work space when repo cloned from remote. Don't think python plugin helps or is needed; does not support Python3 or pipelines.

Comment: @IanW Ok, then what would the shell command look like? 
python  /path/to/python /path/to/filename.py ?
In variable now is: Variable Name: Path , Value: /path/to/python /path/to/filename.py
Is it OK like this?